# WordPress overwrite old uploaded file

Tags: wordpress

how do I set WordPress to overwrite files when uploading a file with the same name as a previously uploaded file? By default, WordPress changes the file name. If I have a file uploaded as image1.png and the try to upload a new one with same file name, the second file will be name image11.png. I want WordPress to replace the old file with the new one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following to your functions.php file should work:

```
add_filter( 'sanitize_file_name', 'filename_filter_wpse_28439', 10, 1 );

function filename_filter_wpse_28439( $name ) 
{
    $args = array(
        'numberposts'   => -1,
        'post_type'     => 'attachment',
        'meta_query' => array(
                array( 
                    'key' => '_wp_attached_file',
                    'value' => $name,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
    );
    $attachments_to_remove = get_posts( $args );

    foreach( $attachments_to_remove as $attach )
        wp_delete_attachment( $attach->ID, true );

    return $name;
}
```

With the above if you upload a file that is already uploaded, it will overwrite that image. The above was sourced from [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85848), but tested on WordPress 3.9.2

Comment: This is not working for me. The old file is still retained and the new file is uploaded with the file name suffixed by a incremental number. Have you tested the solution on your side?